# Is it possible to display time in seconds of video when UIImagepicker is cropping video and can I get back to crop screen when I click choose once?

Tags: ios, swift, crop, imagepicker

I am doing a video crop functionality using UIImagepicker (by setting allowsEditing = true).

There are three things I need to do:

1. Crop video with minimum duration condition (15 seconds).
2. Need to display seconds(of video inside crop indicators user setting up) at crop screen after picking video from gallery.
3. After picking video and cropping it and when image picker is dismissed I need to open back the cropping screen not gallery on some button click.

My question is are these three requirements can be fulfilled by iOS default imagepicker or not.
If yes then please show me some way.

Comment: There's very little you can customize about the default picker. I'm not sure if displaying seconds is possible.

Comment: You can make your own picker, though

Comment: @aheze I have very tight timelines. So, can't write one. If you have any link that would be great

Comment: [PryntTrimmerView](https://github.com/HHK1/PryntTrimmerView) doesn't show the duration, but because it's open-source you can customize it